# Cool Down period for Stakes

Tags: staking

I'm looking for the number of epochs a stake is locked after it has been deactivated. Is this number fixed or can it vary. i'm aware of the warmup/cooldown-rate, but to simplify the assumption is that we are below this rate.

example:

- epoch x: delegate stake
- epoch x+?: stake is active
- epoch y: deactivate stake
- epoch y+?: stake
  is available for withdraw

If you could point me to the resource where this is defined or maybe there is even a rpc method i can call to get this information.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this](https://solana.com/staking#overview/delegation-timing-considerations) answer your question?

Stake activation/deactivation is the same as warming-up/cooling down. The warm-up period is simply the time between when the stake is delegated and when it becomes `active`. The cool-down period is the between when a stake is un-delegated and when it becomes `deactivated` and okay to be withdrawn.

The answer to how long that takes is simply whatever time is left till the next epoch. An epoch is usually a little above 2 days. If a stake is delegated right at the beginning of the current epoch, then the warm-up period would be ~2 days. If a stake is deactivated 1 day into the current epoch, then the cool-down period would be ~1 day(the time left till the next).